# how to remove x button in model dialogue page in apex18.2

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-18.2

How to remove "X" (close) button on a modal page in Apex 18.2?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to include this into the page's inline CSS property:

```
button.ui-button.ui-widget.ui-state-default.ui-corner-all.ui-button-icon-only.ui-dialog-titlebar-close { 
 visibility: hidden !important; 
}
```

Also, into page's Javascript, Function and global variable declaration, put

```
var button = parent.$('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close'); //get the button
button.hide(); //hide the button
```

Comment: Right; piece of JavaScript is missing. I've edited my message, have a look. I tried it, works OK for me.

Comment: can u guide me why page peocessing is slow in apex?? and whats is the solution

Comment: Enable debugging, run the page, view debug results. Graph will show long blue lines for all queries that take a lot of time so - pay attention to those.

Comment: brother can u me guide me please how to make custom user in apex 18.2 and give rights

Comment: This is a new problem so - you should create a new question. Meanwhile, have a look at documentation, here: https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-18.1/HTMIG/creating-workspace-and-adding-Oracle-AE-users.htm#HTMIG29452 . There's no use in copy/pasting that over here.